# Split rows and calculate new values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["a", 0], ["b,c", 2]], columns = ["name", "value"])
```

Which looks like this:

```
   name  value
0     a      0
1   b,c      2
```

When there is a comma in column `name`, I want to split that row and distribute the number from `value` equally between the new rows. So, the result must be:

```
   name  value
0     a      0
1     b      1
2     c      1
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Plan**
*This is the same plan for both `pandas` and `numpy` versions*

- get a list of lists
- find the lengths of those lists
- divide the values by the lengths as this acts to distribute
- repeat reduced amount of value by the same length as this now counteracts the reduction such that the sum is the same as before
- reconstruct a dataframe with new series

---

**`pandas`**

```
lol = df.name.str.split(',')
k = lol.str.len()
pd.DataFrame(dict(
        value=df.value.div(k).repeat(k).values,
        name=lol.sum()
    ))

  name value
0    a   0.0
1    b   1.0
2    c   1.0
```

**`numpy`**

```
lol = np.core.defchararray.split(df.name.values.astype(str), ',')
k = [len(l) for l in lol]

i = (df.value.values / k).repeat(k)

pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([np.concatenate(lol), i]),
    columns=['name', 'value']
)

  name value
0    a   0.0
1    b   1.0
2    c   1.0
```

---

**Timing**

```
%%timeit
lol = df.name.str.split(',')
k = lol.str.len()
pd.DataFrame(dict(
        value=df.value.div(k).repeat(k).values,
        name=lol.sum()
    ))

1000 loops, best of 3: 843 µs per loop


%%timeit
lol = np.core.defchararray.split(df.name.values.astype(str), ',')
k = [len(l) for l in lol]

i = (df.value.values / k).repeat(k)

pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([np.concatenate(lol), i]),
    columns=['name', 'value']
)

1000 loops, best of 3: 207 µs per loop
```